# gameObject rotates when camera rotates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a UI menu for a game, and I dragged in a GameObject to serve as a representation of what will be placed down if you select it. When I attach a script for its rotation and run the game, it tilts downward with the tilt of the camera, even though there is no script linking the camera and the object.

Canvas is in `ScreenSpace - Camera` mode.

Rotation Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BuildList : MonoBehaviour {

    //Floats
    public float speed = 10f;

    void Update ()      
    {       
         transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (-90f, transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z + (speed * Time.deltaTime));   
    }       
}
```

The x-rotation in the inspector is the one that is rotating. When I rotate the camera downwards, the value the x-rotation in the inspector gets is -155, while the x-rotation of this object should be fixed at -90.

Comment: Your scrip here works just fine in my environment. You must have some other script causing the problem.

Comment: I also have a camera movement script, maybe that's affecting it? But this is also a 3d model that is rotating in UI.

Comment: Screenshot your transform hierarchy, the inspector properties of the camera, and your object.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hw9qln
http://prntscr.com/hw9qsg
http://prntscr.com/hw9r3f

Comment: Your object is inside a canvas. Show its inspector properties too.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hw9sm3

Comment: I'm at a loss...

Answer (score 0):

This may or not solve your problem, but I have a tip:

Don't ever use transform.eulerAngles for iterative update. It could cause [Gimbal Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock). Use [Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) if possible.

I suggest replace the code with this:

```
void Update ()      
{       
     // Note: the axis to rotate may different than what you expect. experiment with it
     transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * (speed * Time.deltaTime), Space.World);   
}
```

And set the object rotation at (-90,0,0) before the game begin.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for willnode pushing me in the right direction, I found code in unity Documentation and modified it so it only rotates the z-axis of the object.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

```
transform.Rotate(0, 0, Time.deltaTime * speed);
```